# Cannot access Grandparent class constructor

Tags: java, android

I've create 3 classes just look like this:

```
public class A{
   protected int x;
   public A(){
      this.x=0;
   }
   public A(int x){
      this.x=x;
   }

   public void doSomething(){
      x=1;
   }
}



public class B extends A{
   @Override
   public void doSomething(){
      x=2;
   }
}



public class C extends B{
   protected int y;
   public C(){
      super();
      y=0;
   }
   public C(int x, int y){
      super(x);//Error
      this.y=y;
   }
   @Override
   public void doSomething(){
      x=3;
      y=3;
   }
}
```

My IDE(Android studio) returned this error:

> Error:(26, 8) Gradle: error: constructor B in class B cannot be
>   applied to given types; required: no arguments found: int reason:
>   actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I'm so sorry if this question came from my ignorance of OOP, but I'm really obstructed and honestly need help from you guy, please. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are not inherited by subclasses.  This means that `B` does not inherit `A`'s two constructors.  Whenever you don't create any explicit constructor, the Java compiler creates an implicit default constructor that takes no parameters and does nothing besides implicitly call the superclass constructor.

The default constructor in `B` is why the first constructor in `C` works.  It explicitly calls it with `super()`.  But because there is no `B` constructor that takes an `int`, the call to `super(x)` in `C` is an error.

When you create the explicit constructor `B(int)`, that will get the call to `super(x)` to compile in `C`'s second constructor.  Because you will now have an explicit constructor, there won't be an implicit default constructor any more, so you will also have to create an explicit no-arg constructor in `B` so that the call to `super` in `C`'s first constructor will still compile.

Comment: I feel curious about class B, It still accepting the constructors of class A as 
 its constructor, like `B b = new B(10);` still work. So why C cannot access that kind of constructor?

Answer (score 0):

At the place of the error a one argument constructor of `B` is called. However, `B` does not have a one argument constructor. It has only the zero argument default constructor.

You need to add a zero argument and a one argument constructor to the class `B`.

Comment: I have done something like `B(int x){ super(x)}` as a temporary solution! However there is a problem if as I have more constructor in class A like: `public A(int x, boolean choice){if(choice) this.x = x; else x = 0;}` and wanted to expand it in class C, then I have to create a constructor in class B, and it looks pretty redundant!